# Java Input and Output

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, filewriter, dataoutputstream

Explain the difference between the outputs of the following two fragments of code for outputting an int i to a file:

i)

```
PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("ints.txt"));
outfile.print(i);
```

ii)

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ints.dat"));
out.writeInt(i);
```

I think the Printer writer takes a string and tranforms it into a stream of unicode characters, whereas  dataoutput stream converts the data items to sequence of bytes.

What more would you add?

Comment: Sounds like homework. If it is so, please tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Files only contain byte, so it all ends up as bytes in the end.

A String is already a stream of characters. When you write a String to a file it has to turn it into a stream of bytes.

An int is four bytes.  writeInt() turns it into a big endian number.

Answer (score 1):

From [`DataOutputStream` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html):

> A data output stream lets an
>   application write primitive Java data
>   types to an output stream in a
>   portable way. An application can then
>   use a data input stream to read the
>   data back in.

From [`PrintWriter` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

> Prints formatted representations of
>   objects to a text-output stream.

Everything is just bytes, but they represent different things. With a `DataOutpuStream` you get bytes that you can read back directly to your primitive Java type `int`, whereas with a `PrintWriter` you don't.

Answer (score 0):

possibly repeating what was already said, but just to make it more explicit:

when you use a printwriter, and say you have an int value of 65 -- the print writer will print 2 characters: '6' and '5'

when you use an outputstream, this prints bytes so it will write to the file a byte with the value of 65 -- this happens to be the character code in ASCII/UTF-8 for 'A' so if you open up the file in a text editor you will see an "A" character -- rather than '6' followed by '5' as above.